# React: How to import a node module that creates a React element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 repos:

1. my main web app
2. my shared component library, being imported as a node module through package.json

Both of them use React. In my main web app, I'm just importing the component files of my shared component library directly like so:

Switch.js (in my shared component library)

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch } from 'antd';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { CloseOutlined, CheckOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';

const StyledSwitch = styled(Switch).attrs({
  checkedChildren: <CheckOutlined />,
  unCheckedChildren: <CloseOutlined />
})``;

export default StyledSwitch;
```

My main web app:

`import Switch from 'my-shared-component-lib/components/Switch';`

However, I'm getting this error:

```
../my-shared-component-lib/components/Switch.js
SyntaxError: /Users/edmundmai/Documents/src/my-shared-component-lib/components/Switch.js: Unexpected token (9:19)

   7 | 
   8 | const StyledSwitch = styled(Switch).attrs({
>  9 |   checkedChildren: <CheckOutlined />,
     |                    ^
  10 |   unCheckedChildren: <CloseOutlined />
  11 | })`
  12 |   &.ant-switch {
```

Is there something I have to install so that my imports will work?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use a React component as an object value in this manner:

```js
{
  checkedChildren: <CheckOutlined />,
  unCheckedChildren: <CloseOutlined />
}
```

The `<` is not valid syntax for the start of an object value (hence the "Unexpected token" error).

What you may want to try instead is to use a [`Prop Factory`](https://styled-components.com/docs/api#attrs) offered by `styled-components` instead, e.g.:

```js
const StyledSwitch = styled(props => <Switch
  checkedChildren={<CheckOutlined />}
  unCheckedChildren={<CloseOutlined />}
  {...props}
/>)``;
```

I haven't used the `styled-components` library, but I think it should work based on what I see in this [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/delicate-smoke-w9dy4?file=/index.js) (which I derived from this [official example](https://codesandbox.io/s/8gx39?file=/index.js) from Ant Design's [Switch](https://ant.design/components/switch/) documentation).

Here's a [comment](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/issues/1449#issuecomment-420087359) from the `styled-components` GitHub issues that might also be worth looking at.

Comment: I just tried the syntax you suggested but it still didn't work. Same error. Thanks for the effort though

Comment: That's odd. There shouldn't be anything invalid about the syntax that would result in the same "Unexpected token" error if {<CheckOutlined />} and {<CloseOutlined />} are wrapped in curly braces on both sides.